# Xpath for finding text inside of an anchor tag using class

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and trying to extract the text inside an anchor tag using xpaths. The anchor tag has a class called test for example.

Example:

```
 <a class="test"> This is the text i need </a>
```

This is what i currently have: `//a[@class="test"]/`

How can I grab the text inside here using the anchor tag and class?

Comment: `xpath('//a[@class="test"]/text()')`

Answer (score 0):

The safe way should be:

```
selector.xpath('//a[@class="test"]/text()').extract_first(default='your default value')
```

This will help you extract the text and handle the None case also!